# Missing required parameters for [Route: about] [URI: - Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel

I have created an app for multiple locations where i have location code in the url and the user can change the country. However, i have a issue with the urls i.e., with the hrefs

web.php

```
group(['prefix' => '{country}', 'middleware' => 'country'], function(){
  Route::get('/', 'Frontend\PagesController@index')->name('welcome');
  Route::get('/about', 'Frontend\PagesController@about')->name('about');
});
```

in my layouts/app.php menu i have `<a href="{{ route('about') }}">`

But i get an error

```
Missing required parameters for [Route: about] [URI: {country}/about]. (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\ezcures\ezcures\resources\views\layouts\app.blade.php) (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\ezcures\ezcures\resources\views\layouts\app.blade.php)
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you've set your routes up (by specifying a *route group* that requires a parameter `{country}`), a URL to an about page would take the following format:

```
https://yourdomain.com/{country}/about
```

When you're trying to generate a URL for an about page, you're not telling Laravel what to put in place of `{country}` (which is a required parameter), which is why you're seeing that error.

The resolution is to simply pass a parameter to the `route()` function call, like this:

```
<a href="{{ route('about', ['uk']) }}">
```

Which will generate a URL like:

```
https://yourdomain.com/uk/about
```